# Undefined index pass variable with javascript to php

Tags: php, javascript, variables

I am making an "updating" pages with JS jquery..

But in my updateit.php i just get Undefined index on all my fields. I dont know why.

Here's the form:

```
<form action="javascript:updateit()" method="post"> 
<b>+ Giv points for at være online:</b><br>
Points hvert. <input type="text" size="1" id="gpe" name="gpe" value="<?=$row["gpe"]; ?>"> Sekundt.<br>
<b>+ Hvor mange points skal der gives(online):</b><br>
<input type="text" name="gpm" id="gpm"  size="1" value="<?=$row["gpm"]; ?>"> Points.<br>
<b>+ Points for videoklip:</b><br>
<input type="text" name="gpv" id="gpv" size="1" value="<?=$row["gpv"]; ?>"> Points.<br>
<b>+ Points for battle:</b><br>
<input type="text" name="gpb"  id="gpb" size="1" value="<?=$row["gpb"]; ?>"> Points.<br>
<b>+ Points for kommentar:</b><br>
<input type="text" name="gpk"  id="gpk" size="1" value="<?=$row["gpk"]; ?>"> Points. & + <b>for 10 kommentare:</b>
<input type="text" name="gpk10"  id="gpk10"  size="1" value="<?=$row["gpk10"]; ?>"> Points.<br>
<b>+ Points for spil:</b><br>
<input type="text" name="gpg"  id="gpg"  size="1" value="<?=$row["gpg"]; ?>"> Points.<br>
<b>+ Points for sjov:</b><br>
<input type="text" name="gps"  id="gps" size="1" value="<?=$row["gps"]; ?>"> Points.<br>
<b>+ Points for SC tryout:</b><br>
<input type="text" name="gpsc" id="gpsc"  size="1" value="<?=$row["gpsc"]; ?>"> Points.<br>
<b>+ Points for første gang redigering i profil:</b><br>
<input type="text" name="gpep" id="gpep"  size="1" value="<?=$row["gpep"]; ?>"> Points.<hr>
<b>- Points for at fjerne videoklip:</b><br>
<input type="text" name="gpRv"  id="gpRv" size="1" value="<?=$row["gpRv"]; ?>"> Points.<br>
<b>- Points for at fjerne battle:</b><br>
<input type="text" name="gpRb"  id="gpRb" size="1" value="<?=$row["gpRb"]; ?>"> Points.<br>
<b>- Points for at fjerne indhold i "Sjov" sektionen:</b><br>
<input type="text" name="gpRs"  id="gpRs" size="1" value="<?=$row["gpRs"]; ?>"> Points.<br>
<b>- Points for at fjerne tutorial:</b><br>
<input type="text" name="gpRt"  id="gpRt" size="1" value="<?=$row["gpRt"]; ?>"> Points.<br>
<b>- Points for at fjerne spil:</b><br>
<input type="text" name="gpRg"  id="gpRg" size="1" value="<?=$row["gpRg"]; ?>"> Points.<br>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Opdater!"/> 
</form>
<div id="insert_response"></div>
```

updateit.php:

```
<?php
$gpm= $_POST['gpm'];
$gpe= $_POST['gpe'];
$gpv= $_POST['gpv'];
$gpb= $_POST['gpb'];
$gpk= $_POST['gpk'];
$gpk10= $_POST['gpk10'];
$gpg= $_POST['gpg'];
$gps= $_POST['gps'];
$gpsc= $_POST['gpsc'];
$gpep= $_POST['gpep'];
$gpRv= $_POST['gpRv'];
$gpRb= $_POST['gpRb'];
$gpRg= $_POST['gpRg'];
$gpRs= $_POST['gpRs'];
$gpRt= $_POST['gpRt'];
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO member_pointsystem (gpm, gpe, gpv, gpb, gpk, gpk10, gpg, gps, gpsc, gpep, gpRv, gpRb, gpRg, gpRs, gpRt) VALUES ('$gpm', '$gpe' ,'$gpv', '$gpb', '$gpk', '$gpk10', '$gpg', '$gps', '$gpsc', '$gpep', '$gpRv', '$gpRb', '$gpRg', '$gpRs', '$gpRt')") or
                die(mysql_error());
                echo "works";
?>
```

(i know my variables in PHP isnt safe, but im just testing..)

and the script:

```
/* ---------------------------- */
/* XMLHTTPRequest Enable */
/* ---------------------------- */
function createObject() {  
var request_type;
var browser = navigator.appName;
if(browser == "Microsoft Internet Explorer"){
request_type = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}else{
request_type = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
return request_type;
}

var http = createObject();
/* -------------------------- */
/* INSERT */
/* -------------------------- */
/* Required: var nocache is a random number to add to request. This value solve an Internet Explorer cache issue */
var nocache = 0;
function updateit() {
// Optional: Show a waiting message in the layer with ID login_response
document.getElementById('insert_response').innerHTML = "Arbejder.. "
// Required: verify that all fileds is not empty. Use encodeURI() to solve some issues about character encoding.
var gpe= encodeURI(document.getElementById('gpe').value);
var gpm= encodeURI(document.getElementById('gpm').value);
var gpv=encodeURI(document.getElementById('gpv').value);
var gpb= encodeURI(document.getElementById('gpb').value);
var gpk= encodeURI(document.getElementById('gpk').value);
var gpk10= encodeURI(document.getElementById('gpk10').value);
var gpg= encodeURI(document.getElementById('gpg').value);
var gps= encodeURI(document.getElementById('gps').value);
var gpsc= encodeURI(document.getElementById('gpsc').value);
var gpep= encodeURI(document.getElementById('gpep').value);
var gpRv= encodeURI(document.getElementById('gpRv').value);
var gpRb= encodeURI(document.getElementById('gpRb').value);
var gpRg= encodeURI(document.getElementById('gpRg').value);
var gpRs= encodeURI(document.getElementById('gpRs').value);
var gpRt= encodeURI(document.getElementById('gpRt').value);
// Set te random number to add to URL request 
nocache = Math.random();
// Pass the login variables like URL variable
http.open('get', 'updateit.php?gpe='+gpe+'&gpm=' +gpm+'&gpv=' +gpv+'&gpb=' +gpb+'&gpk=' +gpk+'&gpk10=' +gpk10+'&gpg=' +gpg+'&gps=' +gps+'&gpsc=' +gpsc+'&gpep=' +gpep+'&gpRv=' +gpRv+'&gpRb=' +gpRb+'&gpRs=' +gpRs+'&gpRg=' +gpRg+'&gpRt=' +gpRt+'&nocache = '+nocache);
http.onreadystatechange = insertReply;
http.send(null);
}
function insertReply() {
if(http.readyState == 4){
var response = http.responseText;
// else if login is ok show a message: "Site added+ site URL".
document.getElementById('insert_response').innerHTML = ''+response;
}
}
```

(ive heard you can pass with jQuery much easier too, but i never figured it out, so i will take that on another question, so please dont remind me.)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You have mixed GET vs POST

Comment: Cant find where ive mixeed it? besides the http.open(get) but i changed to post

Comment: Sending via post is slightly different. See this http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax_xmlhttp_using_post.php also, study the difference between encodeuri and encodeuricomponent. You want encodeuricomponent in this case.